# What is the best way to handle the traffic coming to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a 5 nodes Kafka cluster now, which is deployed in all client services. There is a chance of increasing the cluster node count from 5 to 7. Right now, we have configured only the first 3 node endpoints in all client services. What if when we add a new node to the Kafka broker, as we cannot add the new broker endpoints to all the client services?.

What would be the ideal solution to handle this? I pretty know familiar with the Kafka has the internal load balancer concept which works seamlessly. But I wanted to have an LB or Route53 to handle my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to have LB infront of kafka brokers so that if scaling up or scaling down kafka broker nodes, you dont have to update the client boostrap configuration everytime?

If yes, then yes you can have it, but please checkout below how kafka handles the incoming connections.
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't remove all three of those brokers, your clients will be fine and able to resolve the remaining brokers via the bootstrap protocol